# Seagate/LaCie NasOS - enable volume encryption on non-supported device?

Tags: disk-encryption, whole-drive-encryption

According to the guide at https://www.seagate.com/gb/en/support/kb/nas-os-4x-setting-up-volume-encryption-006007en/ there should be an option to encrypt a volume on devices running NAS OS 4.0. That option is missing from my [LaCie 5big Pro](https://www.lacie.com/gb/en/support/network-storage/5big-nas-pro/) although it is running NAS OS 4.0.

According to the Seagate/LaCie support, the option is missing because my device doesn't support this feature. This is usually "a qualified truth", especially in the context of a Linux based OS. I assume the web based guide to prepare volumes is just an interface to a bunch of command line commands. I therefore asked the support for how to format and encrypt a volume from the command line but they refused to give me that information. The leads to a couple of questions

1. There should be a way to "eavesdrop" the command this guide executes in the background, shouldn't it? Maybe by following the process that way I could figure out how to prepare an encrypted volume. How can I "eavesdrop" this?
2. Anyone that knows how to do this from the command line? Or can perform (1) and figure it out?
3. Since NAS OS is Linux based it should be OSS and the source available somewhere (although not super easy to find, at least not for me) - any suggestions for how to figure out the answer to this question by reading the source (and find the source)?

---

Edit: found the source code https://www.lacie.com/files/lacie-content/download/drivers/5bigNASPro_GPL_4.3.19.7.zip

Comment: Unfortunately getting http 403 (forbidden) when trying to download the zip you linked to.

Comment: @MC68020 I just tried again and could download the link without problems.

Comment: OK!… My browser still beign unhappy, I managed to find my way using wget. OMG! That the source code for the whole thing ! zip tar of bzippe… Anyway… Il try to search for calls to cryptsetup. ;-)

Comment: @MC68020 I have done some searching in the source, I am not sure it uses cryptsetup. It could be that they use Python and the kernel module instead. Does that make sense?

Comment: I can't tell yet. I am only discovering this system (per pure curiosity). What I believe (from my, for the time being noob standpoint) is that either the linux cryptsetup standard is used OR your system relies on some cryptsetup-unrelated bespoke that would necessarily rely on some hwdata-like database (in order to get the knowledge of your device's capabilities)

Comment: In this latter case, the solution would be **at your own unsupported risks** to bruteforce the database or add whatever statement to whatever quircks list telling that you device actually supports the feature. (Unless being 101% sure there is something wrong in the device's capabilities description, I would personally not want that.)

Comment: @MC68020 There is also a VirtulBox enviroment for developing for NAS OS, here https://www.seagate.com/nasos/SDK/0.7/getting_started/index.html , that might be interesting for you.